# Christoffel symbols of the first kind

Tags: differential-geometry

Given a simple surface $\vec x(u,v)$ with following  first fundamental form coefficients: 
$g (u,v)=\begin{bmatrix}
  1 & 0 \\
  0 & g_{uv}(u,v)
 \end{bmatrix}$, my professor has noted the following: 
$<\frac{\partial \vec x^2}{\partial u^2}, \frac{\partial \vec x}{\partial v}>=\Gamma_{uu|v}=0$.

I understand that this is zero but I don't understand the first equation. Is this simply the definition of the Christoffel symbols of the first kind?

Comment: Yes, it is more or less the definition.

Comment: Could you give me the definition, that goes well with this equation here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A definition (not the unique) of the Chrisoffel symbols is the following:
Given a regular surface $\vec{x}(u,v)$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$, if we set 
$$
\vec{x}_u=\frac{\partial\vec{x}}{\partial u}\\
\vec{x}_v=\frac{\partial\vec{x}}{\partial v}
$$
and
$$
\vec{n}=\frac{\vec{x}_u\times\vec{x}_v}{|\vec{x}_u\times\vec{x}_v|}
$$
then the system of vectors $B=\left\{\vec{x}_u,\vec{x}_v,\vec{n}\right\}$ is a basis.
The Christoffel symbols can be defined as the coefficients of the expansion, in such a basis, of the second derivatives of $\vec{x}$, i.e.
$$
\vec{x}_{uu}=
  \frac{\partial^2 \vec{x}}{\partial u\partial u}=
  \Gamma_{uu}^u\vec{x}_u+\Gamma_{uu}^v\vec{x}_v+L\vec{n}\\
\vec{x}_{uv}=
  \frac{\partial^2 \vec{x}}{\partial u\partial v}=
  \Gamma_{uv}^u\vec{x}_u+\Gamma_{uv}^v\vec{x}_v+M\vec{n}\\
\vec{x}_{vv}=
  \frac{\partial^2 \vec{x}}{\partial v\partial v}=
  \Gamma_{vv}^u\vec{x}_u+\Gamma_{vv}^v\vec{x}_v+N\vec{n}
$$ 
Ref.: Pressley, Elementary Differential Geometry, p.172.